# Android CordovaWebView issue with PhoneGap API

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I am trying to use CordovaWebView in the below mentioned way
public class TechTimeMainActivity extends DroidGap implements CordovaInterface{

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000); 
    CordovaWebView webview = new CordovaWebView(this);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new CordovaWebViewClient(this, webview) {         
        @Override         
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)         
        {           
            Log.i(TAG,"Overridden URL Outside IF-->"+ url);
            if(url.contains("OGTE"))
            {
                String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                Log.i(TAG,"Cookie for new url-->"+ cookie);
                Log.i(TAG,"Overridden URL Inside IF-->"+ url);
                view.clearSslPreferences();
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
                return true;
            }

            return true;         
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"Finished Loading-->"+ url);
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
                    // Get the cookie from cookie jar.
                    String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                    if (cookie == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG,"Cookie-->"+cookie);
        }

    }); 

     webview.setWebChromeClient(new CordovaChromeClient(this) {

            public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String         sourceID) {

            }

            @Override  
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final android.webkit.JsResult result)   
            {  
                new AlertDialog.Builder(myApp)  
                    .setTitle("javaScript dialog")  
                    .setMessage(message)  
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,  
                            new AlertDialog.OnClickListener()   
                            {  
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)   
                                {  
                                    result.confirm();  
                                }  
                            })  
                    .setCancelable(false)  
                    .create()  
                    .show();  

                return true;  
            };  
          });
    setContentView(webview);   
    webview.loadUrlIntoView("file:///android_asset/www/index2.html"); 

}

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_tech_time_main, menu);
        return true;
 }
```

}

The problem is if I call my loadurl method using super.loadUrl() my phonegap APIs work fine.But if I call my CordovaWebView in the above mentioned way my phonegap apis are not working. Any help on this will be of great use.